# How to identify maven artifact for different Java versions?

Tags: java, maven, version

I have a maven project that is compiled for both Java 1.7 and for Java 1.6.
The 1.7 jar is the default artifact, but I don't know which how to identify the 1.6 jar.

I could add a suffix to the artifact id, to the version, or set a classifier.
Which is the preferred way? What happens when another project `A` depends on the 1.7 jar, project `B` depends on the 1.6 jar, and project `C` depends on `A` and `B`?

Comment: Not sure of the best way to handle this, but if you want to enforce a particular jar version use `<dependencyManagement>` in your `pom`

Comment: What can you do with the Java 7 version, you can't do with the Java 6 version?  Why do you have two versions? I would just have one.

Comment: @PeterLawrey it's Java 7 code. A special compiler is used to create a Java 6 compatible jar. However, the default choice should be the jar created with the default compiler.

Comment: I still don't know why you can't use the Java 6 JAR in Java 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so after some reading, I think classifiers are the way

From the [maven docs](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html)

> classifier:
>   The classifier allows to distinguish artifacts that were built from the same POM but differ in their content. It is some optional and arbitrary string that - if present - is appended to the artifact name just after the version number.
>   As a motivation for this element, consider for example a project that offers an artifact targeting JRE 1.5 but at the same time also an artifact that still supports JRE 1.4. The first artifact could be equipped with the classifier jdk15 and the second one with jdk14 such that clients can choose which one to use.

Then to solve the issue of forcing one jar over an other, in project `C's` pom, use the `<dependencyManagement>` section and specify the classifier there.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

you have to declare in pom.xml file the java compiler version:

```
<build>
    <finalName>skremm_mobile_web</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```